# using multiple translation files in aurelia i18N

Tags: aurelia, i18next

I have a working app using aurelia-i18n. I would like to split translation.json file into multiple files like nav.json, message.json, etc but I am not sure how to do it.
This is how it looks right now.

```html
locale
  |-en
     |- translation.json
```

But I want to change it to this way.

```
locale
  |-en
     |- nav.json
     |- message.json
```

Is it possible to do it? If so, how do I configure it and access values in each file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have multiple resource files and these are called **namespaces** in the [i18next library](http://i18next.com/) (by default you only have one namespace which is called: `translation`) which is used by [aurelia i18N](https://github.com/aurelia/i18n).

You just need to list your namespaces when configuring the plugin with the `namespaces` and `defaultNs` properties inside the `ns` option:

```
.plugin('aurelia-i18n', (instance) => {
        // adapt options to your needs (see http://i18next.com/pages/doc_init.html)
        instance.setup({
          resGetPath : 'locale/__lng__/__ns__.json',
          lng : 'de',
          attributes : ['t','i18n'],
          ns: { 
             namespaces: ['nav', 'message'], 
             defaultNs: 'message'
          },
          getAsync : true,
          sendMissing : false,
          fallbackLng : 'en',
          debug : false
        });
      });
```

See also the [documentation of i18next](http://i18next.com/pages/doc_init.html) and this related github issue: [Using namespaces](https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/issues/12)

Comment: It answers how to use namespaces with different files. But not to use multiple files.