# Using Aurelia with internationalization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, aurelia

I want my Aurelia app to support multiple languages. For example, when a user navigates to www.mysite.com/sv/start, I want them to view the site in Swedish. What is the best approach for solving this problem in Aurelia?

Comment: your question was a bit difficult to understand. rather than close it, i've edited it to a question i can answer, and i'm going to answer that question. I realize that you were looking for server side rendered translations, but I want to suggest the i18n plugin. hope you find this helpful

Answer (score 0):

There is an Aurelia plugin for handling internationalization. Here are some helpful links:

- [GitHub page](https://github.com/aurelia/i18n)
- [Getting started](https://mttmccb.github.io/starting-with-aurelia-i18n/)
- [Aurelia localization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/aurelia/aurelia_localization.htm)
- [Using multiple translation files in aurelia-i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724138/using-multiple-translation-files-in-aurelia-i18n)
- [i18n update announcement](http://blog.durandal.io/2016/03/25/i18n-update-release/)

Answer (score 0):

Since we share translations (web portal based on Aurelia and various mobile applications) we use this approach:

- Translations are in database;
- In Aurelia project we have `LanguageService` class responsible for loading translations from database and taking care about current language and related, language specific, culture information;
- `LanguageService` is instantiated on the login page and then injected among components via `@autoinject` from `aurelia-framework`;
- Each component or page has its own binded labels and properties translated from `LanguageService`;

This approach can be applied in your case because you can parse language id from given route.